# flutter how to pass variables in a http.get request

Tags: node.js, json, express, flutter, dart

All documentation I found about flutter a http.get request get all data from database I want only a specific data that's why I have to pass a variable in my method in this example how to pass a to the server?

```
Future<List<Phone>> getData() async {
String a="bonjour
        http.Response response = await http.get(
            Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.43.24:27017/api/posts/gettdata"),
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
        print(response.body);
        List phonee = json.decode(response.body);
        return phonee.map((phone) => new Phone.fromJson(phone)).toList();
      }
```

the server which will read my request will be a node js server and I want to know how to make a find for the parameters which I passed.

```
router.get('/gettdatae', (req, res, next) => {
    Post.find({imei: {name}}=)
        .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts);
            console.log(posts);
            console.log("ok" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + req.body.imei);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  Future<List<Phone>> getData() async {
    String a="bonjour";
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.43.24:27017/api/posts/gettdata?a="+a),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);
    List phonee = json.decode(response.body);
    return phonee.map((phone) => new Phone.fromJson(phone)).toList();
  }
```